# ajax xmlhttp response is null - javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, null, response

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


                                var xmlhttp;
                                $(document).ready(function (){ 

                                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   
                                });

                                function SubmitCommentAJAX(i){alert();

                                    alert(i.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("commentsScroll")[0].innerHTML);

                                    var thecomment=i.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("styled")[0].innerHTML; 
                                    var commentBox=i.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("commentsScroll")[0];

                                    var request="http://localhost:8080/ituned.com/index?Event=Comment&PostTitle=<%=p.getTitle()%>&PostOwner=<%=p.getUsername_of_Owner()%>&comment="+thecomment;
                                    xmlhttp.open("POST",request,true);
                                    xmlhttp.send();

                                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                                     {
                                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                        {        
                                          var response=xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("theComment")[0].text;
                                          commentBox.insertBefore(response, commentBox.firstChild);

                                       }
                                     };




                                }
                                </script>
```

I get :Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null    for this line:

var response=xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("theComment")[0].text;

The servlet sent the response, because in the debugger it says that the repsonse was received, but anyway here's the code inside the servlet:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
        try {
            response.getWriter().println("<theComment>asasasaasa<br></theComment>");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The browser is chrome. Can anyone tell me why xmlhttp.responseXML is nul??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<br>` is not valid in xml try `<theComment>asasasaasa<br/></theComment>` instead.

Comment: I removed the <br>, and now i get this:

Comment: I removed the <br> and now i get this: Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 index:4227
SubmitCommentAJAX.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: ah ok, that is for commentbox, so it is now my problem to find it. thank you!

Comment: @Vlenorroia use `textContent` instead of `text`